# Hey guys I am having trouble running the apt-update command

Tags: raspbian, networking, debian

I am having issues connecting to the archive.rasbian.org , re installing is not an option since I had just finihsed a project and have to show my work , this issue is usally a simple fix on debian but im new to the rasbeery pi , here is my /etc/apt/sources,list I am from Canada Toronto and need help with the mirror and what to put inside /etc/apt/sources,list. This is what i tried so far

```
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
```

Comment: You have to be joking! Wheezy was replaced in 2015.

Comment: BRO please help me

Comment: @Milliways PLEASE BRO , i need help I found this on google

Comment: Download and install a supported version of the Raspberry Pi OS.

Comment: @Milliways I have  thre right version I just copied some bogus from the web

Comment: If you want help you need to ask a sensible Question.  
Incluing OS e.g Raspberry Pi OS - Bullseye Raspberry Pi OS - Buster  & model.

Post actual command and error messages.

See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `legacy` instead of `archive`.

```
deb http://legacy.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib
```

Jessie and Wheezy are still available. Note that, at some point, you must upgrade, because, since it was moved to `legacy` in 2019, not a single update on the packages were made. So, for example, no security patches.