# I'm unable to install FLAC on my Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, python, audio, linux, software-installation

I'm trying to make a tts program on my Raspberry Pi 3 and I'm using Googles TTS API which requires that I have FLAC installed on the Pi. When I attempt to install FLAC, I'm thrown this error-

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/pyTTS/images $ sudo apt-get install flac

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  flac
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 131 not upgraded.
Need to get 115 kB of archives.
After this operation, 310 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  flac
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main flac armhf 1.3.0-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/f/flac/flac_1.3.0-3_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I've tried updating and fix-missing, to no avail. I'm interpreting the error message as that the link it's trying to retrieve from is broken. Does anyone know a fix for this? Or an alternative I could use to read FLAC in this context?

Comment: Jessie is obsolete last 2017! Try an up to date OS, either Buster or Bullseye.  See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/136149/8697

Comment: If you look at the directory on the repo: [http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/f/flac/], you can see v.1.3.0 is not there, only later versions which likely have newer dependencies as well -- ie., as Milliways suggests, you need to upgrade the OS.  The jessie repos are gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out, `apt` support for `jessie` is no longer available, and your [*best bet*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Best+Bet) may be to upgrade your OS. However, that's not your only option for getting `flac` installed on your `jessie` system.

Three options for installing `flac` (and most other apps) on your `jessie` system are:

1. use the archives
2. "backport" `flac`
3. build and install `flac` from its [upstream sources](https://github.com/xiph/flac)

N.B. I haven't tried all of this myself - I don't have a system older than `buster`. And I can't say which might be *best* or *easiest*; I think that's dependent on your end objective, and on `flac` itself. A quick overview of these options follow. You can find more details online in a search, but here's the gist of it:

##### 1. use the archives:

The archives are a useful resource; the trick is navigating them to find what you need. Ideally, we could still find a `.deb` package for `flac` that's compatible with `jessie`; that would make installation easy: `dpkg -i flac.deb`. If you can't find a compatible `flac.deb`, one alternative is to build `flac` from source... but building a package from source requires the proper tool: `devscripts` - which you may or may not have installed on your system.

I could go on & on with this, but let me instead provide the following list. If you elect to pursue this option, we can ponder the details.

- `flac` .deb files: https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/f/flac/
- `flac` src files: http://sourcearchive.raspbian.org/main/f/flac/
- `devscripts` .deb files: https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/d/devscripts/

If you peruse these URLs, I think you'll find that the .deb option only goes back to Debian 9, a.k.a. `stretch`. It might be worth trying to install the `stretch` version on your `jessie` system.

After some trial and error to learn the dependencies of `flac`, I was able to get `flac ver 1.3.2` installed on my `buster` system as follows:

```bash
$ wget https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/libo/libogg/libogg0_1.3.2-1+b2_armhf.deb 
$ wget https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/f/flac/libflac8_1.3.2-2+deb9u2_armhf.deb 
$ wget https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/f/flac/flac_1.3.2-2+deb9u2_armhf.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i libogg0_1.3.2-1+b2_armhf.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i libflac8_1.3.2-2+deb9u2_armhf.deb 
$ sudo dpkg -i flac_1.3.2-2+deb9u2_armhf.deb
$ which flac
/usr/bin/flac
$ flac --version
flac 1.3.2
```

And so this approach was successful on my `buster` system. Because of the limited dependencies of `flac`, I feel this may also work on your `jessie` system. I don't feel there's much risk involved; `dpkg` is fairly *smart* about installing packages, and also has an option for removing whatever it does install. But if it accomplishes nothing else, this drill will increase your appreciation of `apt`!  :)

If you need/want to remove the packages using `dpkg`, follow this sequence:

```bash
$ sudo dpkg --purge flac
$ sudo dpkg --purge libflac8
$ sudo dpkg --purge libogg0
```

##### 2. backporting:

[Backporting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backporting) is a term for installing newer applications on older systems. There are a couple of decent *"how-to"* documents specific to Debian located [here](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/docs/staff/procedures/backporting-packages/) & [here](https://wiki.debian.org/SimpleBackportCreation). The `flac` source packages are [located here](http://sourcearchive.raspbian.org/main/f/flac/).

**However**, backporting may require (certainly they make it easier) some specialized tools in `devscripts` - and as we've seen already, the `devscripts` package in .deb format isn't available for `jessie`. That makes backporting seem a much less feasible option - at least, I'm not inclined to try it.

##### 3. build and install from upstream sources:

AFAIK, `gcc` (GNU C compiler) and `git` are included with *all* RPi distros. With these tools, you should be able to download (`clone`), build and install from the [`flac` GitHub repository](https://github.com/xiph/flac). If you were doing this on an `apt-supported` system (as of today, that's `buster` or `bullseye`), I would strongly urge you to [install this with `Stow`](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/InstallSoftwareWithStow.md), but we can get by without it:

- `clone` the `flac` repo into a folder `flac` in your home dir:

```bash
$ git clone https://github.com/xiph/flac.git 
$ cd flac
```

- follow the build & install instructions in the README file in the section `Building in a GNU environment`: ***Unfortunately, there seem to be some missing pieces from this puzzle: There is no `config` file in the repo!***  Hopefully this will be corrected soon, but in the meantime, it appears Option 1 is all that's available.